# Use wordpress password to login into android application

Tags: wordpress

May I know how my user use the user information in wp-user of wordpress to login into application? The password for wordpress is like this $P$B, I cannot login with using these password. I am new with wordpress, can someone give me a guide for me to solve solution? Thank you

Comment: Prepare the API to authenticate the user from application and see the response which api returns.you can refer the following link to build an API which communicate with WP 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introducing-the-wp-rest-api--cms-24533

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress REST-API for Application Development. 
For example, it has a support for authentification:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

If you don't want using API and want quicker solution, then you may need to create some small function by using wp_check_password( $password, $hash, $user_id )  function of WordPress.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password

Comment: mean include wordpress php file to my own php file? because my application i used php to do login and register.

Comment: No. You can send CURL request from php file to WordPress website. For example with this params:  yoursite.com?user=username&pass=password.  Then in wordpress side, in functions.php write small function which detects if $_POST parameters called "user" and "pass" exists, then compare it to WP user DB via wp_check_password() function. If it is OK, return WP_USER data, if not, return false(incorrect password message)

Comment: got link or tutorial about this? I am no so clear with wordpress now

Comment: i think you need to hire someone for this small task. Without knowing WP fundamentals and security it is hard to build such integration